# How ti make unit test for S3Events getRecords?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I was asking if it's possibile to make a unit test in java for this method:

```
public s3Request(S3Event s3Event){
    this.record = s3Event.getRecords().get(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to test this method.
Although the construction of the `S3Event` is a bit tricky.

If you look into the [Java Doc of the S3Event](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-events/latest/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/events/S3Event.html) you'll see a public constructor that accepts a `List<S3EventNotification>` as parameter.
A `S3EventNotification` itself has a public constructor that accepts a `List<S3EventNotificationRecord>`. And last but not least the `S3EventNotificationRecord` has also public constructor.

This means your Testcode could look something like this:

```
@Test
void test(){
    var eventNotificationRecord = new S3EventNotificationRecord(...);
    var eventNotification = new S3EventNotification(List.of(eventNotificationRecord));
    var event = new S3Event(List.of(eventNotification));

    var componentUnderTest = new UnknownClass(...);
    componentUnderTest.s3Request(event);

    assertEquals(eventNotificationRecord, componentUnderTest.getRecord());
}
```